# ORA-01467: sort key too long

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following select which produces an error. [1]: ORA-01467: sort key too long
This is from an old block of code and I am unable to remove columns from the tables. Is there another way to fix this error?

```
SELECT distinct c_id,
   LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(uW,','))
   KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS uW
FROM   (SELECT distinct c_id,
           uW,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY uW) AS curr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY uW) -1 AS prev
    FROM   tmp2)
GROUP BY c_id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND c_id = PRIOR c_id
START WITH curr = 1;
```

Comment: I am not sure what causes the error - I don't see too many columns or too many aggregates at any point in the query. But: For starters, there is no point in selecting **DISTINCT** <whatever> in the subquery, since the `row_number()` values will already be distinct. Then, there is no need to use the same `row_number()` function twice; just use it once to create `curr`, and change the `connect by` condition to `curr = prior curr + 1`. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy that is still producing the same error for me

Comment: Try the usual troubleshooting steps... does the subquery run successfully if it is run by itself? Does the outer query run fine without the DISTINCT keyword (which is, again, redundant anyway)?

Comment: It might be useful to show the definition of `tmp2` and give some idea of the data involved; and also say which version and patch level your database is on. What are you actually trying to do - this seems to be reinventing `listagg()`m so are you on an old version that doesn't include that function?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole I was able to sort this using listagg(). If you want to answer the question , code was select c_id, 
       listagg(uw, ',') within group (order by uw) as uw
from tmp2
group by c_id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Oracle docs, the aggregated length of the sorting/grouping columns + some overhead must not exceed the block size (usually 8K). With newer Oracle versions and e.g. charset AL32UTF8, the column size of tmp2.uW ortmp2.c_id might be longer than 4000 chars and longer than 8000 bytes.